# Invalid Constant Value Text Flutter Google Fonts

Tags: flutter, google-fonts, flutter-text

I am having Text which i am styling with Google fonts and is working okay but when i add const before Text i get Invalid Constant Value Error

Below is how i have implemented without const

```
Text(
    'Voila',
     style: GoogleFonts.dawningOfANewDay(fontSize: 30),
),
```

Below is how i have tried implementing with const

```
const Text(
        'Voila',
         style: GoogleFonts.dawningOfANewDay(fontSize: 30),
),
```

Below is how i have tried making google fonts constant but the error still persists

```
const Text(
              'Voila',
              style: const GoogleFonts.dawningOfANewDay(fontSize: 30),
            )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to remove `const` from your code because `constant values` are expected to be `hard coded` but the font style or font family you are using is coming dynamically to const won't allow this.

```
Text(
         'Voila',
         style: const GoogleFonts.dawningOfANewDay(fontSize: 30),
     )
```

Comment: so there is now way i can use GoogleFonts as constant

Comment: Why not you just have to store that font family locally as a assets then you can use that font family with const.

Comment: okay i will try that

Comment: Okay after trying if it works then mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Download `dawingOfANewDay` Google font and make it available in the asset folder.

And use as:

```
const Text('This is hammersmithOne from Google Font',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'dawingOfANewDay')
```

For futher reference refer [this](https://www.flutterbeads.com/google-fonts-in-flutter/) article.